# Telling the rspec which input to use in a interactive ruby script?

Tags: ruby, command-line, automated-tests

I defined different test-cases:

- Running the script with a URL as a parameter, which should be passing.
- Running the script without a parameter, which should fail.

Now I'm interested in how to extend the test to giving input to that interactive script. After starting the script I'm using:

```
def self.check_target
  @entrygroup = ask 'What kind of entry do you have? (Interpret or Group)'

  case
  when @entrygroup == 'Interpret' then
    @firstname = ask 'Whats the first name of your interpret?'
    @surname = ask 'Whats the surname of your interpret?'
    $folder = "#{@surname}_#{@firstname}/Youtube-Music"
  when @entrygroup == 'Group' then
    @group = ask 'Whats the name of the group?'
    $folder = "#{@group}/Youtube-Music"
  else
    puts 'Just the entries "Interpret" or "Group" are allowed'
    abort('Aborted')
    puts 'Breakpoint'
  end
end
```

How can I tell the test which input to use?

Comment: Without any context I don't know what you're asking about.

Comment: The context is that project: https://github.com/saigkill/youtube_dlhelper/tree/master/lib

Comment: The context needs to be summarized in your question so we don't have to chase it down. "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't meant to answer your asked question; It's to help you write better code.

I'd probably write it something like this to clean it:

```
def self.check_target

  entry = ask 'What kind of entry do you have? (Interpret or Group)'

  subdir = case entry
          when 'Interpret'
            [
              ask('Whats the first name of your interpret?'),
              ask('Whats the surname of your interpret?')
            ].join('_')

          when 'Group'
            ask 'Whats the name of the group?'

          else
            puts 'Just the entries "Interpret" or "Group" are allowed'
            puts 'Breakpoint'
            abort('Aborted')
          end

  "#{ subdir }/Youtube-Music"
end
```

It's questionable whether `$folder` in your code should be a global. Usually you want to avoid that completely and either return a value directly from the method without assigning it, like above or use an assignment to a class variable:

```
@@folder = "#{ subdir }/Youtube-Music"
```

Returning a value, instead of assigning it, makes more sense to me, because you're trying to get a path to use.

Also, assigning to instance variables inside a class method makes no sense. Just use local variables.

Add both things together and it looks like you're not comfortable with how variable scope works. You might want to work on that.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your idea. I tried out the code, but actual it produces that error: http://pastebin.com/9YmeN5f5
It looks like there is any problem with the brakets.

Comment: Don't put errors or code in off-site links. If that link breaks the question or comment is worthless. The key information I needed was the line-number and the error message. The problem is, `ask` needs parenthesis around the string being passed in. Ruby was trying to treat the comma as a divider between multiple parameters, and `ask` only takes one. See the code change above.

Comment: Thanks. That looks more beautiful than mines. :-)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure it's beautiful, but you're welcome. I think a part of what defines well-written code, is that it flows into our brains easily. We don't spend time having to decipher what it's doing. It's not necessarily simple code, but it's clear and concise and does what it appears to do. That helps later, when we're debugging, and are scanning for problem spots. If we can easily "[grok](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grok)" what is happening then debugging is easier.